# Is there Exec Shield buffer overflow protection for Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, security

Is there Exec Shield buffer overflow protection for Ubuntu?

I tried to enable Exec Shield on Ubuntu 12.04 with the following command

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.exec-shield=1
```

but it said

```
error: "kernel.exec-shield" is an unknown key
```

If not, what is the equivalent solution for Ubuntu and how can I install and enable it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu has NX protection enabled by default. This either uses hardware NX when the CPU supports it, or uses NX emulation in the kernel (the equivalent of the Red Hat Exec Shield patch).

For more information, visit:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features

more specifically:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#nx

Answer (score 0):

Open your /etc/sysctl.conf file:

`# sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf`
`#### Add the following lines:`

`###enable ExecShield protection`

`kernel.exec-shield = 1`

`###enable random placement of virtual memory regions protection`

`kernel.randomize_va_space = 1`

Save and close the file.

To load sysctl without reboot type this command below ::
 `sysctl -p`

Comment: Can you confirm that Ubuntu supports the kernel.exec-shield key? Last I checked it didn't. This seems to be a Red Hat/Fedora feature so far.